# Python os.path.isfile returns the wrong answer if I create a file right after that

Tags: python, file-exists, os.path

I'm totally confused,
I'm using `os.path.isfile` a line before a create a file, sth like this

```
assert not os.path.isfile(file), "file exists"
pd_df.to_csv(file)
```

and surprisingly it returns an exception, but if I add a 5 sec delay in between it will work. This is total nonsense to me since this is not a parallel programming, why is this happening?

Comment: can we see the code in context ?

Comment: Do you get a `TypeError` or `AssertionError`?  How is `file` defined initially?